# Stacked Proactive Messages w/ Botframework

Tags: node.js, botframework

I'm trying to do the "Send a dialog-based proactive message" example on this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-proactive-messages … and have it resume with the dialog that was interrupted.  The code doesn't work and then I noticed the note about botadapter.js.  I tried to follow the "here" link but am getting a 401 error.

Is the code sample up-to-date because it looks like bot is expecting a function not an object for that 4th parameter.

Comment: I think the link is supposed to target [this page](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/Node/core-proactiveMessages/startNewDialog/index.js).

Comment: Try using one of these examples instead: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/core-proactiveMessages

Comment: The simple bot.beginDialog(address, "*:/survey"); interrupts any dialog the client may have been in without being able to resume afterwards.

I'm trying to do bot.beginDialog(savedAddress, "*:/survey", {}, { resume: true }); as shown in the sample on the referenced page from the documentation.

Comment: @MattB. The UniversalBot.beginDialog() method doesn't work like that. You can see the full method signature here: https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.universalbot.html#begindialog 

`beginDialog(address: IAddress, dialogId: string, dialogArgs?: any, done?: function): void`

Comment: Also, it looks like some files were not copied over when the example repository was ported over.  For the original example code (including the missing `botadaptor.js` file), see: https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/botFramework-proactiveMessages

Comment: Yes please refer to my original message.  I've looked at the signature and the examples and agree, but your documentation is incorrect.  Is there a way to make an interrupted dialog resume?  

Documentation link: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-proactive-messages)

Section: Send a dialog-based proactive message

Code: 
    // Set resume:true to resume the previous dialog;
    // else, set resume:false to resume at the root dialog.
    bot.beginDialog(savedAddress, "*:/survey", {}, { resume: true });

Comment: Yes, the sample code in the docs site article is incorrect. I have submitted a PR to fix them.  You can see a complete working example of interrupting and resuming a dialog here: https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/botFramework-proactiveMessages/blob/master/node/startNewDialog/index.js

Comment: Docs page has been updated with working code examples. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-proactive-messages

Comment: So if the code sample requires botadapter.js, why not write the code sample to use it?  Does not work as written.

I've adapted my code to use botadapter but so far my proactive dialog isn't being initiated.  I'm a little confused as to what the beginDialog 'opts' and 'done' parameters should be.

Comment: @MattB. You can find the [class definition here](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.universalbot.html#begindialog). If you have further questions about this code example, please open an issue on [BotBuilder GitHub.](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/new) Thx

Comment: Due respect, that is NOT the class definition for the botadapter version of beginDialog, which is what I'm asking about.  Can you address that specifically please?

Comment: 2 months later and no response and nothing has changed.  The example code does not work with botadapter.  Someone else submitted a github issue on this back in July.  

Will this be fixed?